# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{n-k} = \binom{m+1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can you show that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{n-k} = \binom{m+1}{n}$$

by using an index shift and the following relationship, which is assumed to be true:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m+k}{k} = \binom{m+n+1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing $m$ with $m-n$ gives $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m-n+k}{k}=\binom{m+1}{n}$. Changing the dummy variable viz. $k\mapsto n-k$ gives what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the following indentity (and induction on $m$) which is not hard to verify: 
$${n\choose k}+{n\choose k+1} = {n+1\choose k+1}$$

Comment: Does that apply to the first equation? Because I already used that identity to show the second equation, which I regard as a prerequisite here

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @Katharina You could always derive the identity recommended in this answer from the result you're assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Using the the symmetry of the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ combined with
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$ with the understanding that $\binom{i}{k}=0$ for $i<k$
we wind up with

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{n-k}=
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{m-n}=
\sum_{i=m-n}^m \binom{i}{m-n}=
\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{i}{m-n}
=\binom{m+1}{m-n+1}=\binom{m+1}{n}
$$