# Where Error in evaluate summmation :$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, fake-proofs

Where Error in  evaluate summmation :$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$$

I know that :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n+1}{m}$$

But I does't know error My proof this :
we have :
$$\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n+1-k}{m-k}-\binom{n-k}{m-k-1}$$

Let :$$a_k=\binom{n+1-k}{m-k}$$

Therfore:
$$\binom{n-k}{m-k}=a_k-a_{k+1}$$
This implies that :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=a_0-a_{m+1}=\binom{n+1}{m}-\binom{n-m}{-1}$$
I think this is wrong, because I do not know the exact value of this :$\binom{n-m}{-1}$I appreciate your interest

**If anyone has another interesting method I'd be happy to share it**

Comment: The value is just zero for negative bottom number. This site has many posts with all kinds of proofs for it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why 0??

Comment: Why? Read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527831/is-n-choose-k-defined-when-k-0-what-about-n-k), namely the accepted answer. It's because of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{n-k} = \binom{m+1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455036/show-that-sum-k-0n-binomm-kn-k-binomm1n) Also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819414/proving-combinatorics-identity-sum-k-0mn-k-choose-m-k-n1-choose-m).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I got the answer to the question, thanks

Comment: @DietrichBurde This differs from my summation a little

Comment: The first duplicate has $m$ and $n$ interchanged (so just rename it), the second is exactly your summation. Which difference do you see?

Comment: Thank you very much